# See game progress before joining a game

Tags: battlefield-3

Is there a way to see how far along (how many tickets left) is before joining the game?

Example: I want to play  Operation Firestorm, I join a server with said level only to find that one of the teams only has 15 tickets left and the round will be over in 3 minutes.

Comment: This information is prone to change, as the game browser is updated regularly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.   Without having Admin rights on the server, Here is all of the information you can see:

- REGION
- SHOW HUD
- TEAM BALANCE
- BULLET DAMAGE MODIFIER IN %
- SHOW MINIMAP
- 3P VEHICLE CAM
- VEHICLES
- REGENERATIVE HEALTH
- ## OF TK BEFORE PLAYER IS KICKED
- KILL CAM
- USE MINIMAP SPOTTING
- PLAYER HEALTH IN %
- PLAYER MAN DOWN TIME IN %
- FRIENDLY FIRE
- USE 3D SPOTTING
- SHOW ENEMY NAME TAGS
- KICK IDLE PLAYER AFTER SECONDS
- BAN PLAYER AFTER OF KICKS
- PLAYER RESPAWN TIME IN %
- ONLY SQUAD LEADER SPAWN
- SERVER ADDRESS
- Map rotation
- Server name
- Total in game player list
- Server Ping
- Ranked
- Preset
- Punkbuster
- Password
- Current map

Comment: Actually, you can see more, by clicking on the link with the server name on the right, right above "JOIN SERVER" button.
Just not the current game status.

Comment: Well correct, I was just saying on in game status, not server settings.  Complete server settings are viewable prior to entering as well via @Bora 's method ( and through a search filter)

Comment: You can also see the scores of the players in the game, so that should be a good feel for what stage the game is in.

Comment: Good point @Emerica. Unfortunately, max ticket count varies from game to game, and also among servers, so the only thing one would know for sure is, whether the game has just started or if it's been underway for a while

Comment: @Bora Yeah, it would be relative, but its an estimate at least.